# Azure Cosmos DB - 'RequestDisallowedByPolicy' error while creating container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

While creating cosmos db container I am getting below error:

```
Error creating database: {"code":403,"message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"RequestDisallowedByPolicy\",\"target\":\"scolNextGen\",\"message\":\"Resource 'scolNextGen' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{\\\"policyAssignment\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Allowed resource types custom\\\"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-policy-requestdisallowedbypolicy#solution)

> For security or compliance, your subscription administrators might
>   assign policies that limit how resources are deployed. For example,
>   your subscription might have a policy that prevents creating Public IP
>   addresses, Network Security Groups, User-Defined Routes, or route
>   tables. The error message in the Symptoms section shows the name of
>   the policy. To resolve this problem, review the resource policies, and
>   determine how to deploy resources that comply with those policies.

Comment: Do I need to check with administrator to grant the access?

Comment: yes you need to, this happens in most of the organization